# Keras InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1,8,32] vs. [1,10,32]

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

It stops training at the beginning of the first epoch.

The error is:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1,8,32] vs. [1,10,32]
     [[Node: training_8/RMSprop/gradients/loss_8/time_distributed_9_loss/mul_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _class=["loc:@train.../Reshape_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](training_8/RMSprop/gradients/loss_8/time_distributed_9_loss/mul_grad/Shape, training_8/RMSprop/gradients/loss_8/time_distributed_9_loss/mul_grad/Shape_1)]]
```

I'm not sure if the error might be the format of the training data.
This is a sample of train_x:

```
[array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  3,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], dtype=int32), array([15, 16, 17, 18, 19], dtype=int32), array([20, 16, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], dtype=int32), array([27,  1, 17, 28, 18, 29, 30, 31, 24, 32], dtype=int32), array([33,  1, 17,  3, 34, 35, 36, 37, 18, 38], dtype=int32), array([39, 16, 40, 28, 41, 42], dtype=int32), array([39,  1, 40, 28, 41, 43], dtype=int32), array([44,  6,  3, 45], dtype=int32), array([15, 16, 40, 46, 47, 48,  3, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53], dtype=int32), array([ 0, 54, 28, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59], dtype=int32)]
```

This is a sample of train_label

```
[array([0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 0, 7], dtype=int32), array([0, 5, 8, 9, 9], dtype=int32), array([10,  5,  8,  9,  7,  9,  7,  7], dtype=int32), array([10,  1,  8,  1,  9,  9,  3,  0,  7,  2,  7], dtype=int32), array([10,  1,  8,  1,  9,  9,  9,  7,  9,  7], dtype=int32), array([0, 5, 8, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int32), array([0, 1, 8, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int32), array([11,  0,  1,  9], dtype=int32), array([ 0,  5,  8,  7, 12, 13,  1,  2,  9,  9,  5,  6], dtype=int32), array([ 0, 14,  1,  2,  2, 12,  4, 15], dtype=int32)]
```

This is the code:

```
n_vocab = len(unique_words) #1517
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(n_vocab,100))
model.add(Convolution1D(128, 5, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(GRU(100,return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')))
model.compile('rmsprop', 'categorical_crossentropy')

n_epochs = 30
train_x = [np.asarray(x, dtype=np.int32) for x in encoded_sentences]
train_label = [np.asarray(x, dtype=np.int32) for x in encoded_POS]

for i in range(n_epochs):
    print("Training epoch {}".format(i))

    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=len(train_x))
    for n_batch, sent in bar(enumerate(train_x)):
        label = train_label[n_batch]
        # Make labels one hot
        label = np.eye(n_classes)[label][np.newaxis,:]
        # View each sentence as a batch
        sent = sent[np.newaxis,:]

        if sent.shape[1] > 1: #ignore 1 word sentences
            model.train_on_batch(sent, label)
```

Comment: What is `n_vocab`?

Comment: @MiloLu edited, 1517

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Length asymmetry between sent and label. The third sent length in train_x is 10, but the third label length in train_label is 8.